# remove vim bottom line? with mode, line, column, etc

Tags: vim

Is it possible?..

I mean the most bottom line of screen, to get just full terminal screen of buffer lines.

This is not the line controlled by the `laststatus` variable.

Comment: I kind of like this idea for some occasions. The command line could 'pop' up when `:` is pressed.

Comment: How will you know whether you're in I or N mode? You press : in I mode, it writes :; you press : in ?what? to enter the command. No, sorry, it would be just too confusing. Vim is a modal editor, it needs a command line. And just by asking for it, I suspect you spend more time in I mode than in any other ... meaning, you're doing something wrong while in there. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I will know of the mode by the means of my short-term memory, this is perfectly sufficient. I asking for it to demonstrate by folded vim outlines (I do my notes in nested dashed lists, with custom foldexpr for that) via projector, unfolding and extending these while tutoring.

Comment: There must be *some* way of doing this, even if it’s hacky/painful.

Comment: @ldigas this is not at all the case. It’s *the exact opposite*. I’m always into insert or visual mode only for *moments*, exactly the quantity of time it takes to type a word or add a few characters of syntax/linenoise, then I’m immediately out without even thinking about it. The *chord* I use to insert text includes the escape/jj to leave insert mode.

Comment: @elliottcable - I still hold that it would be a bad idea. I don't like the sound of it, nor visually nor functionally.

Comment: @elliottcable I honestly don't think you're going to find a way to do this without making some pretty big changes to vim's source.  This has been asked over and over again in #vim to no end.

Comment: @RandyMorris yeah, that's basically what I'm getting from all angles. I may have to go patch it myself at this point, though I'm a little afraid that it's an assumption that will lay tendrils deep into the rest of vim's source code. /=

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140898/vim-hide-status-line-in-the-bottom , autohide request: http://superuser.com/questions/619765/hiding-vim-command-line-when-its-not-being-used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently no, you need at least one line available for ex commands. You can disable the mode message and ruler if you like with:

```
:set nosmd   " short for 'showmode'
:set noru    " short for 'ruler'
```

But the line will still be there.

Comment: how weird! do i need to recompile vim for this simple thing?

Comment: and, as was mentioned, ex line could easily pop up over bottom line of the buffer.

Comment: well, empty line is bearable after all.

Answer (score 2):

If you try

```
:set cmdheight=0
```

or

```
:set cmdwinheight=0
```

It says it has to be a positive integer.  So my guess would be no.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/40120

[edit]

On a second look at this link, it appears this first command did work for someone.  I can't duplicate it, however (gvim or vim on a pc).

Comment: for me cmdheight must be > 0.

Comment: For me as well.  That is why I think it is probably not possible in a straightforward way.